# Checking if DOM is standing still

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, dom, watin

There is this rather interesting problem. I will provide some context because a lot of people might ask why somebody would need something like this.

**Background info**

Have to make unit (integration) tests for large and complicated .net web forms app.
Currently using visual studio 2010, nunit, watin 2.1, ie9. There already are a few hudred rather complicated unit tests but they are slow, not very reliable mainly because of timing issues. So have to get execution time down from many many hours to something more reasonable and keep them reliable.

**Current problem**

I have some problems with waiting for async requests to be completed. (This needs to be done to get updated page from screen for testing.) The current situation looks something like this:

```
//Function is called after making an async request to wait for DOM to be updated
    public static void WaitForAsyncPostBackToComplete(this Browser browser)
    {
        int waited = 0;
        bool isInPostback = true;
        while (isInPostback)
        {
            if (waited > AjaxWaitTime)
            {
                throw new Exception(string.Format(
                    "Looks like Ajax reqest timed out. Test waited {0} milliseconds.",
                    waited));
            }
            isInPostback = IsInPostback(browser);
            if (isInPostback)
            {
                // Request is not completed, wait a bit for next polling.
                Thread.Sleep(AjaxSleepTime);
                waited += AjaxSleepTime;
            }
        }
        // IMPORTANT: Wait for DOM to be actually updated???
        Thread.Sleep(300);
    }

    // Check if something is in postback now.
    private static bool IsInPostback(Browser browser)
    {
        string function =
            "(  typeof(Sys) === undefined " +
            "|| Sys == undefined || Sys == 'undefined' || Sys==null " +
            "|| typeof(Sys.WebForms) === undefined " +
            "|| Sys.WebForms==null || Sys.WebForms==undefined|| Sys.WebForms=='undefined'" +
            "|| typeof(Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager) === undefined) " +
            "|| Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager==null || Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager==undefined|| Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager=='undefined'" +
            "? true " +
            ": Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().get_isInAsyncPostBack();";

        string result = browser.EvalSafely(function);
        return Convert.ToBoolean(result);
    }
```

So I am pooling very often to check if ajax request is completed with IsInPostback() function. This seems to work pretty fast and reliably.

However I think that IsInPostback() says that everything is done before it is actually inserted in DOM. That means we got the answer, but we need some time to insert it here. Because of this I need that ugly Thread.Sleep(300) line to wait for DOM to be updated. I would like to make that line go away by somehow determining when DOM is updated more precisely and reliably.

**The real question**

Is there any good way to determine that DOM is loaded in IE9 with async madness going on? I have been thinking about simply getting entire DOM in variable (how could it even work if DOM is changing) and polling to check for changes in it. If no changes are made for like last 50ms, I could stop waiting. Is there any good way to do something like this?

Any thoughts are welcome ....

Comment: I don't know the answer - but for someone with 1 rep - (+1) for a nicely laid out question!

Comment: well you could listen to the change event on the DOM structure of your page, its obvious that DOM will be modified when something is updated over it.

Comment: I think that you mean https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events
I have looked at them and there are some problems. They do not seem to be well supported in IE9, they are kind of an overkill because I do not want to listen to changes all the time and I really cannot mess a lot with main solution that is outside of unit testing project by adding event listeners.

PS - Adding comment by pressing enter is pretty frustrating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is very old, but it still gets some views, so I thought about adding some afterthoughts about this problem.

After reading some documentation (that is not very detailed for such a specific case) and doing some experiments I came to the conclusion that Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().get_isInAsyncPostBack(); method  should exit (return true) only after DOM update is completely finished.

However it turned out to be pretty hard to use this kind of approach with high precision because in ASP.NET Web Forms and we did not have complete control of the JS that was generated. So if there are multiple requests after one user action because of nested update panels, or there are some delayed updates or some inconsistencies in execution of JavaScript this kind of approach is not 100% stable.

In the end there probably are two possible partial solutions:

1. Accept that this kind of approach does not work accurately in 100% of the cases and deal with it higher levels of abstraction.
2. Add other layers on top of this function (for better dealing with multiple AJAX requests in a row or delayed requests) and combine it with smaller waiting times.

Either way there seems to be no clear cut answer that works in 100% of the cases with no explicit waiting in the thread.

This question is very specific and probably cannot get any answers that could be accepted in the future, but I think it contains some interesting points, so I will leave the question open here and accept these afterthoughts.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the 'Ajax Requests Completed Flag' from javascript and check it in C#.
**HTML:**

```
<input type='hidden' id='hdnRequestCompletedFlag' value='0' />
```

**Javascript:**

```
var NoOfCompletedRequests = 0;
var NoOfRequests = 10; // Your number of requests.
$.ajax({
    ...,
    success: function( data ) { // This function same for all the ajax requests.
        NoOfCompletedRequests++;
        if(NoOfCompletedRequests == NoOfRequests)
            $('#hdnRequestCompletedFlag').val('1');
    }
});
```

**C#:**

```
private static bool IsInPostback(Browser browser)
{
    string function =
        "(  typeof(Sys) === undefined " +
        "|| Sys == undefined || Sys == 'undefined' || Sys==null " +
        "|| typeof(Sys.WebForms) === undefined " +
        "|| Sys.WebForms==null || Sys.WebForms==undefined|| Sys.WebForms=='undefined'" +
        "|| typeof(Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager) === undefined) " +
        "|| Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager==null || Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager==undefined|| Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager=='undefined'" +
        "? true " +
        ": Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().get_isInAsyncPostBack();";

    string result = browser.EvalSafely(function);
    return Convert.ToBoolean(result) && (hdnRequestCompletedFlag.Value == '1');
}
```

Comment: I understand what you are thinking but this might not address the main issue. I think (but am not 100% sure) that IsInPostback() only determines if we got an answer from the server (and it seems to work OK), but it does not say that we have updated DOM with information we received. Am I wrong with this? So the real question is: How do we wait for updating DOM more precisely without simply sleeping for 300ms or something like that because it makes tests run much longer.

Comment: You must be updating the DOM with the data you are getting in the ajax's `success` function. You can then set the flag after you have updated the DOM with the data. Are there other ways your DOM is going to be updated?

Comment: OK, so if all DOM updates are done from ajax success function and DOM updates are completed at the end of this function, this should solve the problem. But, how do we add extra fields and function calls for thousands of pages and ajax calls? About other ways of updating: are there really other ways that this could be done?

Comment: I think this solution would be great for smaller projects. But changing so many things in the main test project that has thousands of pages could be problematic if not impossible.

Comment: Since the actual DOM updates may occur asynchronously add a setTimeout(fn, 0) to the end of the (DOM manipulating) success-handler. So 'fn' will be called after all preceding events from the DOM update completed. Than set some UpdateCompleted-flag..

Comment: I was afraid of that. I do not know a lot about inner workings of JS. But it seems that a lot of stuff with DOM is really done asynchronously and putting something in the end of success function might not guarantee that DOM is not changing anymore.